# Postgres Update table with limit

Tags: postgresql

Postgres fails when I use limit with update statement

I want to update just the first record of a table

```
UPDATE test1 SET name="user101" LIMIT 1;
```

this fails in postgres as I am using limit;

I can do this

```
UPDATE test1 SET name="user101" 
WHERE ID =(SELECT ID FROM test1 LIMIT 1)
```

But to use the above sql I should know the column name (ID) and I don't have access to column name in my case.

I need a sql statement that does not require column name but updates only the first record.

**Update:**

I am using ruby `@db.exec(query)` to execute query

We pass different sql statements like below to the method which calls `@db.exec(query)`

1. update table1 set t1_name = "123" limit 1;
2. update table2 set something = "xyz" limit 1;
3. update table3 set som = "abc" limit 1;

now before calling `@db.exec(query)`

I want to modify the query such that the query won't use `limit`

In this case I have access to table name, column name that I want to update. But I don't have access to any other column names (ID).

Comment: How do you know you want to change column `test1` when you don't have access to the column names?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my question I have access to table name and column name that I need to update.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible design - why don't you know the primary key of your tables? Updates that target a random row in a table seem like something very strange

Comment: This is just for our testing purpose, where we want to update only a single record data (any record).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think this approach has a very bad smell (what kind of application sends updates for random rows to the database), you can use the internal `ctid` column for this which is always available.

```
UPDATE test1 
  SET name = 'user101' 
WHERE ctid = (SELECT ctid FROM test1 LIMIT 1)
```